# Is a static enum initializer called everytime a value is needed?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am considering to use an enum with a static initializer like this:

```
public enum MyEnum{
    ...
    private static HashMap<X, Y> features;

    static {
        features.put(X, new (Y));
    }
    ...
}
```

Is the HashMap going to be reinitialized every time I need a value from it?

Comment: Its between to make the Map `final` (rather than a HashMap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, like all static blocks it's executed only when the type is initialized.

So this will be done only once.

But you should affect a value to your map : you don't do it in the code we see. You should have

```
private static Map<X, Y> features;

static {
    features = new HashMap<X, Y>();
    features.put(X, new Y());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, static block will be executed only once while class initialization. It won't execute on each call to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

No, static initializers only run when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

No, just once.

BTW: [Guava ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) can help:

```
private static Map<X, Y> features = ImmutableMap.of(X1, Y1, X2, Y2...));
```

Benefit:

- No need static block
- One line code
- ImmutableMap means safer, if you just need an immutable Map